# How to get byte data out of string in python?

Tags: python, string, character-encoding, bytecode

I'm having an issue with reading out data from PDFs (not really relevant I don't think). Sometimes, I get the text that I am after, but sometimes I get a long byte-string looking thing, such as: "\uf041\uf073\uf....". My question is how can I get the string that represents back?

```
'''python
file_name = r'\path\filename.pdf'
reader = pp.PdfReader(file_name)
content = reader.pages
text = repr(content[0].extract_text()).split(r"\n")
'''
```

Most of the time this works (4150 work to 235 broken). When it breaks the string looks like either:

```
'''markdown
["\\uf054\\uf072\\uf061\\uf064\\uf069\\uf06e\\uf067",....]
or
["\x14\x1e\r\x11\x0c\x1f\x14\x1a\x0c\'\x16&-+ \x01",...]
'''
```

If I try to create a byte array, or bytes it simply will encode the encoding.

Comment: How do you read the file?

Comment: File is read in using PyPDF2.PdfReader(<filename>)

Comment: Which does not return a string.

Comment: Then doing reader.pages[0].extract_text(). Exactly calling:
repr(content[p].extract_text()).split(r"\n")
with content as reader.pages, and p = 0

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What you've shown is a string. It isn't clearly exactly what you want. Those unicode characters are part of the private use area, they don't have any meaning. You haven't given us any information about what you are actually doing.

Comment: Those are all just strings. They aren't byte strings, i.e. `bytes` objects, they are decoded strings. Those unicode code points are from the private use area. Again, it really isn't clear what you want here. Maybe there is a text encoding issue. We don't even know what library you are using.

Comment: That is what is spat out. I know they are strings, and my questions specifically is getting the value of the string coding (as above), to the actual character it represents.

Comment: do you mean convert: `"\\uf054\\uf072\\uf061\\uf064\\uf069\\uf06e\\uf067"` to `"\uf054\uf072\uf061\uf064\uf069\uf06e\uf067"`

Comment: Convert to the what each of those \\uf054 characters represent, or really just know what is going on. I have made a rough fix for the ucase, but the 'x' case is still not working well enough. I do not understand what they are meant to be.

Comment: Can you please answer my question: do you mean convert `"\\uf054\\uf072\\uf061\\uf064\\uf069\\uf06e\\uf067"` to `"\uf054\uf072\uf061\uf064\uf069\uf06e\uf067"`??

Comment: No, that specifically should convert to 'Trading' This case is ok now, its the \xDD case that is causing me problems now

Comment: An empty-headed approach: `''.join( [chr( ord(x)-0xF000) for x in '\uf054\uf072\uf061\uf064\uf069\uf06e\uf067'])` returns `'Trading'`…

Comment: The characters starting with \x are all between \x00 and \x1f (even the \r is in the range) and thus are control characters that can not be shown by python on console. That is the normal way for python to encode these characters. The same apply for the private use area characters. However some fonts may contain characters in this range. This fonts could be extracted from the file or maybe local installed. Get this fonts and render those strings with something that can handle those fonts.